# well known facts on openness condition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Hi,

I would like to understand and prove the following two "well-known" facts:

1)

If $B$ is a scheme and $P$ a property for which I know:

i) if $B=Spec(V)$ where $V$ is a complete DVR, if $P$ holds on the special point then it holds on the generic point of $B$

ii) $P$ is true on a constructible set of $B$

then $P$ holds on an open subset of $B$.

2)

Assume $B$ integral.
If $P$ true on the generic fiber implies that there exists an open dense of $B$ where $P$ holds then $P$ holds on a constructible set.

Comment: What do you mean by a property here and is there a difference between "P holds on U" and "U has P"?

Comment: Sorry, by "propriety" I meant "property". In my case I have a family $X\rightarrow B$ having a property $P$ satisfying i) and ii)

Comment: The spectrum of a complete DVR has two points, the closed one and the generic one, so I don't understand (i).

Comment: Sorry, now it is fixed.

Comment: A similar question was asked on Stackexchange here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903891/a-corollary-in-kollars-paper Does anybody know the answer to this?